# GSpread exception: 'expected_headers' are not uniques' on different machine

Tags: python, gspread

I have the following code set up:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd


scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keyfile.json',scope)

gc= gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh= gc.open('Spreadsheet') 

worksheet = sh.worksheet(sheetName)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_values())
```

The strange thing is, this code is working fine on my Macbook.
However, if my colleague executes it on his Macbook, he gets this Exception:

```
'GSpreadException: the given 'expected_headers' are not uniques' error
```

I tried to trace the issue and it appears that the spreadsheet contents cannot be correctly loaded by `get_all_values` and therefore all column headers are perceived the same. The assoicated sheet of the spreadsheet certainly has actual content.

It is strange that it works on one machine but not on another, which makes me believe it may be a versioning issue.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand `the spreadsheet contents cannot be correctly loaded by get_all_values`. Can I ask you about the detail of it using the sample input Spreadsheet as an image and the sample output values? About the sample output, can you also provide your expected value?

Comment: Did you check if you use the same version of `gspread` ? This exception has been added recently.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed the version of gspread, as pointed out by @Lavigne958
Downgrading to an earlier version of gspread solved the issue

Comment: Are you sur you are using `get_all_values` (as mentioned in your example)? And not `get_all_reccords`. Both methods have different behaviors

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that in a specific google sheet, two of my column names were exactly identical.